# Listing all JMS queues in Tibco EMS

Tags: java, jms, tibco, ems

I am writing a Java class to browse a Tibco EMS JMS server and show all queues. I'm able to connect without issues and browse specific queues but I am looking for a way to return a list of all queues (with queue depth if possible). I'm not if there is a specific EMS API to use so I am using standard JMS.

I've tried the following code to do a reverse JNDI lookup but it is failing.

```
NamingEnumeration<?> queues = context.list("");
List<String> availableQueuesNames = new ArrayList<String>();
while (queues.hasMoreElements()) {
    NameClassPair element = (NameClassPair) queues.nextElement();
    availableQueuesNames.add(element.getName());
}
```

Which throws this error:

```
javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Not supported
    at com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext.list(TibjmsContext.java:1018)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsContext.list(TibjmsContext.java:484)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.list(Unknown Source)
```

I did some digging and it seems Tibco EMS does not support looking into the JNDI like this. Is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the tibjmsServerAdministrator.java same class provided with Tibco as a guide (and the addAdmin() method), I was able to write code to list all queues:

```
Map<String, TibjmsAdmin> map = new HashMap<String, TibjmsAdmin>();
addAdmin(txtServer.getText(), txtUser.getText(), txtPassword.getText(), map);
_admin = new TibjmsAdmin[map.size()];
map.values().toArray(_admin);

QueueInfo[] info = _admin[0].getQueues(null);
for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
    String queueName = info[i].getName();
    if (!queueName.startsWith("$") && !queueName.startsWith(">")) {
        queues.add(queueName + ", 0");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about Tibco details, but maybe it would work with `listBindings` instead of `list`?

I have done the same thing in a generic way like this:

```
List<Queue> out = new ArrayList<>();
scanJndiForQueues(out, "");

...

private void scanJndiForQueues(List<Queue> out, String path) throws NamingException {
    InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
    Object resource = context.lookup(path);
    if (isSubContext(resource)) {
        NamingEnumeration<Binding> list = context.listBindings(path);
        while (list.hasMoreElements()) {
            Binding binding = list.nextElement();
            scanJndiForQueues(out, path + "/" + binding.getName());
        }
    } else if (resource instanceof Queue) {
        out.add((Queue) resource);
    } // else ignore Topics
}

private boolean isSubContext(Object object) {
    return javax.naming.Context.class.isAssignableFrom(object.getClass());
}
```

Comment: That's a good idea and I played with listBindings() too, but unfortunately it also gives the same problem "javax.naming.OperationNotSupportedException: Not supported".

Comment: Okay... another reason not to use Tibco? That method is not marked as optional.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know why you need to list all the EMS queues, but you can achieve this (and many other things) with the GEMS tool.

Search for it at [tibcommunity](https://tibbr.tibcommunity.com) (you will need an account), or you can download the last version directly from [here](https://api.built.io/v1/classes/page/objects/blt3b5a8aa5d1093caf/uploads/52d3e3315cd92f3faf000f8b?AUTHTOKEN=blt5f6441f47eb4a126e65fe5ce&TENANT_UID=tibbr_tibcommunity_com_tibbr_20).

Comment: Yes you can use GEMS. User wants to be able to access the list of queues from inside of Java. GEMS provides a DOS-style application which will allow the user to view information about different Tibco structures. To my knowledge, GEMS does not have any capability for even cut and paste with strings listed on screen. It will not help with writing a Java program.